# Gnome 2.32 Virtual Desktop Looping

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-10.10, virtual-desktop, workspace

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with Gnome 2.32 and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to make the virtual desktops (workspaces) loop so that moving to the left when on the left-most desktop goes to the right-most desktop.

I know this is possible with Compiz, but it seems like a lot of overhead just for this one feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong keyword when googling for this, I should have used "cycle" instead of "loop".

Anyway, it turns out that the [Unity 2D PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/unity_2d?dist=maverick) for 10.10 had this featured added to it's build of [metacity](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/260655) in February!

So, I just added this PPA to apt, did an update on metacity, logged out/in, and now it works.